# Pronuncia delle vocali "e" e "i" per studente inglese

Tags: english-comparison, pronunciation

Vorrei un consiglio su come aiutare una studentessa (anglofona) che continua a confondere le "i" con le "e". In particolare quando una parola in italiano finisce in "e", lei la pronucia "i". Credo sia un problema piuttosto diffuso, pensa a come un inglese pronuncia per esempio "panettone" "Versace"... pronunciano spesso l'ultima vocale come una "i". Anche "grazie" all'inizio tendono a pronunciarlo "grazii".

Io le ho consigliato di ricordare E di EGG e I di IGLOO ma fa ancora fatica. Mi chiedevo se qualcuno di voi abbia mai avuto questo problema e se conosciate strategie che potrebbero risultare utili in questo caso.

Comment: La tua domanda non mi è del tutto chiara. Stai chiedendo se esistono (o sono esistiti) altri inglesi con difficoltà a pronunciare le vocali "e" e "i" in italiano?

Comment: La /i/ italiana è pronunciata come "sk**i**", non come "**i**gloo".

Comment: @Charo Sto cercando di capire se c'è un modo per aiutare la mia studentessa a ricordare la pronuncia di queste due vocali, magari c'è un trucchetto che non conosco? Il problema sono le "e" e le "i". Per esempio, lei pronucia il nome "Simone" "Simoni".

Comment: @FionaD:  Potresti riscrivere la domanda in modo che sia più claro quello che stai chiedendo, per favore?

Comment: I don't understand how an English native speaker wouldn't be able to pronounce the vowel sound /i/, as it exists in several English words, such as "beach", "seat" and "see". Italian has 2 sounds for E: the open E /ɛ/ (as in Italian "idea") and the closed E /e/ (as in Italian "stare"). The 1st one should be easy: it is pronounced as E in "bed".  The 2nd one is harder because it only happens in the English diphthong /ei/ (eg "say"). I suggest pronouncing some English words with /ei/ really slowly, up until the /e/, in order to understand the position of the tongue when pronouncing it.

Comment: @Charo vorrei un consiglio su come aiutare una studentessa (anglofona) che continua a confondere le "i" con le "e". In particolare quando una parola in italiano finisce in "e", lei la pronucia "i". Credo sia un problema piuttosto diffuso, pensa a come un inglese pronuncia per esempio "panettone" "Versace"... pronunciano spesso l'ultima vocale come una "i". Anche "grazie" all'inizio tendono a pronunciarlo "grazii". Spero di essere stata piu' chiara.

Comment: @FionaD Ho provato a inserire il tuo commento nella domanda allo scopo di renderla più chiara.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista I suspect it is a matter of trying to apply English [phonotactics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonotactics) to Italian words. It's not that the student is physically unable to pronounce the vowels, just that they find them so unnatural in those positions that they unconsciously replace them with other, more "acceptable", sounds

Comment: Ci sono studenti che imparano presto la pronuncia di queste vocali in italiano, e altri che ci mettono più tempo. Purtroppo non conosco strategie efficaci, se non un costante esercizio nella lettura e l’ascolto di radio/tv in italiano.

Comment: Credo sia una tendenza piuttosto comune per gli anglofoni: è recente la storia di “Giuseppi” riferito al presidente del consiglio, durante una visita negli USA.